# At queue not queuing

Tags: bash

I have he following at command:

```
at -q a now
```

I expected that the `-q a` would cause the commands to run sequentially, but they are not. On inspection with `atq` they are all designated the `=` queue meaning that the commands are not being queued rather are all running as soon as they are sent to at.

How can I make them run sequentially?

Comment: Wrap the sequence in a `bash` script?

Comment: Put the synchronization code in the individual jobs?

Comment: Both are options. But if there is an easy solution then that's what I would prefer.